# Identifying numbers in a string list that contains strings and numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string list array that contains strings. Either the values will be a name or number. For example the contents could be:

```
stringList[0]="Mary"
stringList[1]="John"
stringList[2]="4564321"
stringList[3]="Steven"
```

I want to append the contents of the list to a string which I have done through a simple loop but if a number is encountered I want that number to be popped out and handled in a different method and then have the original loop continue looking for strings and appending. Essentially I want to append the non numbers and take the numbers and do something else with them. What functions or tricks can I do so when it is going through the list it will be able to identify a string as a number?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like some basic research would set you on the right path. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the output you want?  You might be able to use the `.Where()` Linq method to filter out the items based on your condition.

Comment: you could have solved this as well using the `char.IsNumberic` Function or `char.IsAlpha` function.. Google works wonders if it's used properly fyi.. please show more effort on your part opposed to getting in a state of panic and expecting others to provide you with a quick fix ..the best way to learn is by doing

Comment: `string tempStr = "Mary";`
`bool _isNumeric = tempStr.ToCharArray().All(x => Char.IsDigit(x));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the string is always a number (not numbers and letters mixed), you an use one of the various `TryParse` methods. I'll use `int` in my example, but you can use whichever fits your needs:

```
int value;

foreach(var s in stringList)
{
    if(int.TryParse(s, out value))
    {
        // s was a number, the parsed result is in value
    }
    else
    {
        // s was something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to determine if it's a number and get its value.

```
int intValue;
if (int.TryParse(str, out intValue))
    // handle as int
else
    // handle as string
```